# Why is Container.DataItem being passed as a string literal?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, data-binding

I'm trying to pass a string value to a javascript function from a LinkButton's OnClientClick event, but the function is receiving "<%# Container.DataItem %>" instead of the value.  Here's the code:

```
OnClientClick="javascript:SaveQuotaGroupCode('<%# Container.DataItem %>');"
```

The container is a collection of strings.  Why is it not evaluating?

EDIT: This is located in a nested ListView.  The datasource for the inner ListView is a property in the datasource of the outer ListView.

Answer (score 2):

`OnClientClick="javascript:SaveQuotaGroupCode('<%# Eval("YourProperty") %>');"`

Also, the collection should be transformed into a comma separated list of values as that is what the signature of the Javascript function expects...

Comment: I thought Container.DataItem represented the current bound data?  The ListView is bound to a string collection property.  I edited the question to include that this is inside a nested ListView.  No matter what I try it passes everything in the script tags as a literal.  Also, the evaluation I'm using works for the Text property.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that worked for me:
    onclick='<%# "chkchange(\"" + Convert.ToString(Container.DataItem["MyId"]) + "\")"  %>'